# How to call Yelp API for access token?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send a POST request to Yelp API to get an access token using these instructions: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started

However, the code below isn't printing anything to the console. I'm not sure what the issue is or if I've set up the POST request properly. What's wrong with my code? :(

foodfinder.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script src="./public/foodfinder.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Food Finder</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    Hello world


    </body>
    </html>
```

foodfinder.js:

```
$(function () {

var API_HOST = "api.yelp.com";
var SEARCH_PATH = "/v3/businesses/search";
var BUSINESS_PATH = "/v3/businesses/";
var TOKEN_PATH = "/oauth2/token";
var GRANT_TYPE = "client_credentials";

var CLIENT_ID = "abc";  // dummy id for stackoverflow purposes
var CLIENT_SECRET = "xyz";  // dummy secret for stackoverflow purposes

var SEARCH_TERM = "food";
var SEARCH_RADIUS = 500;        // radius is in meters
var SORT_BY = "distance";


$.ajax(API_HOST + TOKEN_PATH, {
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        grant_type: GRANT_TYPE,
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("post call error");
    }


})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need the https in the HOST variable, like

`var API_HOST = "https://api.yelp.com";`

when i test the call without the https, i get an error: 
`{"error": {"description": "/oauth2/token", "code": "VALIDATION_ERROR"}}`